# How to integrate font picker on text-view in android.?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an application, so that need to change multiple font on a text view using multiple font picker. I've read many tutorials and code, but still cannot be able to get this feature. I tried Ted codes, Collaborate code and android lib for getting multiple font.

**I need multiple font styles, more than 2-3. Is it possible?**

Comment: http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/fontpreference-dialog-for-android/

Comment: Check this http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/fontpreference-dialog-for-android/

Comment: Yes I had already check this blog, but there is no any font name and font file available for making a font chooser dialog in this link, also not so clear....i want sample with all font file/style abailable